# Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am new in C# I wrote this unitest

```cs
public async Task AddAshtray()
{
    var service = serviceProvider.GetService<IAshtrayService>();

    var Model = new AddAshtrayViewModel()
    {
        Brand = "Lubinski",
        CountryOfManufacturing = "China",
        ImageUrl = "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51xDDJtDbBL._AC_SY1000_.jpg",
        Comment = "Really nice and colorful ashtray.",
        TypeId = 1,
    };

    int expectedReturnId = 1;

    var actualReturnId = await service.AddAshtraysAsync(Model);  // HERE 

    Assert.That(actualReturnId, Is.EqualTo(expectedReturnId));
}
```

and when I create  `var actualReturnId = await service.AddAshtraysAsync(Model);`  I recive this error

> Error  CS0815  Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable

when I remove `await` the error appear to next line with code.

I google it, without success and I think this is special case so for that reason I didn't find anything.

Comment: `AddAshtraysAsync` returns `void`, I presume?

Comment: You need to check the definition of AdddAshtraysAsync method

Comment: I'm guessing it returns `Task`, not `Task<T>`. When you await `Task`, it has no result, thus `void`. (And without `await`, `var` was inferring `Task`.)

Comment: Roman Ryzhiy - yes

 vivek nuna - I check it and found out what I am doing 
 
madreflection - yes it return Task and I just decide to change my method to return Task<T> and it works :)

Thank you everyone for your feedbacks thay was useful!